# Using OnClick from another activity in another package

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclick

I'm trying to call from a Fragment an OnClick method from the parent activity in another package.

The code for the onClick methods are:

```
public static void Back(View v) {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);
}

public static void Next(View v) {
    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
}
```

And here's the code for the Fragment where I want to call these methods from

```
public class Level1Question1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    Button buttonQuestion = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonQuestion);

    What do I do here?

    return rootView;
```

Comment: you need to take reference from your activity in your fragment that right ?

Comment: Firstly, don't get into a habit of defining `public` static methods in an `Activity` - it's a bad practice which could cause you major problems. Second, the correct way for a `Fragment` to access its parent `Activity` is through a callbacks interface. A `Fragment` should be modular, self-contained and re-usable and, as such, shouldn't know what type of `Activity` it is attached to. Handle the `Button` presses in the `Fragment` and call a relevant callback method to show the button has been pressed. As long as the parent `Activity` has implemented the callback methods, it can act appropriately.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Now, can you give me an example of how to implement that? Thanks!

Comment: Look at "Creating event callbacks to the activity" https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

Comment: Also look at "Communicating with other fragments" https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html - I know that's not what you want to do but it gives other examples of using the callback interface approach.